# How to view/check local storage of a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I opened my background.html and checked "Resources -> Local Storage". It's always empty. But based on my debug info in codes local storage seems to work fine.

So it works, but i want to see them.

I also checked "Resources -> Local Storage" in a normal page and it shows data well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Chrome internal page (chrome://appcache-internals/) will help you. It shows the cache for HTML5. Is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: hmm... I don't think so. but it's good know such a page. thanks :)

Comment: Get the list with chrome://chrome-urls/. Maybe there is one link that will help.